# How to sort this list of strings by the time and date embedded in them?

Tags: python, sorting

List items:

```
'Cam218-10-03_16_05-21-54.jpg',
'Cam318-10-03_17_04-21-54.jpg',
'Cam418-10-03_16_04-21-54.jpg',
'Cam218-10-02_16_05-21-54.jpg',
'Cam318-10-02_17_04-21-54.jpg',
'Cam418-10-02_16_04-21-54.jpg',
'Cam218-10-02_16_04-08-31.jpg',
'Cam318-10-02_16_04-08-30.jpg',
'Cam418-10-02_16_04-08-30.jpg',
'Cam518-10-02_16_04-08-35.jpg',
'Cam618-10-02_16_04-08-36.jpg',
'Cam118-10-02_16_04-08-36.jpg',
'Cam118-10-03_16_05-21-54.jpg',
'Cam218-10-03_16_05-21-54.jpg',
'Cam118-10-03_16_05-21-54.jpg',
'Cam118-10-03_16_04-08-31.jpg',
```

Using python, how to sort this with time stamp? I want the output as:

```
'Cam118-10-03_16_04-08-31.jpg',
'Cam218-10-02_16_04-08-31.jpg',
'Cam318-10-02_16_04-08-30.jpg',
'Cam418-10-02_16_04-08-30.jpg',
'Cam518-10-02_16_04-08-35.jpg',
'Cam618-10-02_16_04-08-36.jpg',
```

I have tried this:

```
file=open("ram.txt","r")
data=file.readlines()
data.sort()
for i in data:
    print(i,end='')
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: file=open("file.txt","r")
data=file.readlines()
data.sort()
for i in data:
    print(i,end='')

Comment: you should post your code *in your question*, not as a comment.

Comment: What portions of each string represent the time and date?

Comment: you can leverage the `sorted` function and providing the `key` function to return the part you want to sort. eg., `sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[4:24], reverse=True)` for you case. for detail about `sorted` build-in-function, please refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open("ram.txt","r")
data=file.readlines() #assuming data now has the images in a list
dates = []
for img in data:
    img = img.split('-')[1] #remove the cam118 etc and just get date strings
    dates.append(img)
zipped_pairs = zip(dates, data) #zip them together 
sorted_dates = [x for _, x in sorted(zipped_pairs, reverse=True)]
```